# Access unnamed nested array values?

Tags: php, arrays

I am working with a function in PHP that has a return value of a whole bunch of nested arrays. The layout looks like:

```
array(
    'key1' => 'value',
    'key2' => 'value',
    'nested1' => array (
        array (
            'id' => 12,
            'authors' => array("one", "two", "three")
        )
     )
)
```

The authors key is what I want to access, but from what I have tried to use, I cannot access the values. How can I access the values from authors?

Comment: $array['nested1'][0]['authors']

Comment: print_r($array['nested1'][0]['authors']). try this? if variable name is `$array`

Comment: If it's unnamed, then it's numbered, starting from 0 and incrementing in steps of 1 for each additional value - Read the [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) paying particular attention to Example #4